# How to make python see a particular window?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using python 3, where i am using ImageGrab to see the portion of the screen.
The thing I want to do is get the full application window may be it of any size that is the program will get all the window that I want.

My Code Is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
while(True):
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,580,580))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    #frame = img_np
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: I am getting this.]
I am getting this:

But I want this.The Full Window:
[image]

I also want to grab the window anywhere on the screen.